# Por que as pastas no meu diretório do github ficaram cinzas e vazias?

Tags: git, github

Aqui está como elas ficaram:

[image: Github]

Enviei com o bash usando git push --force porque o push normal não estava funcionando. Alguém sabe me dizer o que aconteceu e como resolver? as pastas não estão vazias no diretório original do meu pc mas no github por isso ficou cinza em vez de azul que é a cor que eles usam pra pastas.

Comment: Você tentou criar algum submódulo? Qual a saída de `git remote -v`? Se você registrou submódulos eles tem que ser válidos no GitHub também. Se não você pode sempre remover os submódulos com `git submodule deinit NomeDoModulo`. Por sinal, caso você tenha clonado esse repositório, talvez seja mais produtivo levar essa dúvida [para a Loiane](http://loiane.training/).

Comment: Apaguei tudo e criei um novo diretório e não adiciona as pastas. Quando eu faço o git push origin master aparece pra mim: usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

    -f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    --tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=<push|fetch>]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from

Comment: O meu git não reconhece pastas mesmo não estando vazias.

Comment: Você primeiro precisa fazer um `git init`, adicionar e commitar as mudanças localmente, [adicionar o repositório remoto](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/) e só então fazer o `push`. Mas de qualquer forma essa é uma outra pergunta. o motivo pelo qual suas pastas ficavam cinzas e vazias era submódulos quebrados.

Comment: fiz td isso e mesmo assim:  fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 2):

> "fiz td isso e mesmo assim: fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a
>   git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please
>   make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists."

Faz o seguinte:

1. Remove a pasta .git do teu repo local
2. Executa: git init
3. Executa: git remote add origin "url do teu repositorio"
4. Executa: git status

No 4 você será capaz de ver as revisões que tem no teu repo local marcadas como mudança no repo. Aí é só adicioná-las (git add .) e comitá-las (git commit e git push origin master).